# Find pset3 "\expected an exit code of 0, not 1"

Tags: c, find, binary-search, cs50

all mighty community of CS50ers on StackOverflow!

I have coded the sort and search functions of pset3, find, but I just don't get why I get this message. It is as if in the while loop the first if were never executed.

Any hints?

```
#include <cs50.h>

bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{    
    if (n < 1)
    {
        return false;
    }   
    else
    {   
        int start = 0, end = (n-1);
        while (end >= start)
        {   
            int median = (end - start) / 2;
            if (median == value)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (values[median] < value)
            {
                start = values[median + 1];
            }
            else 
            {
                end = values[median - 1];
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
}

void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int smallest_index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (values[i] > values[j])
                smallest_index = j;
        }
    temp = values[smallest_index];
    values[smallest_index] = values[i];
    values[i] = temp; 
    }
}
```

[Click Here to See Error Message from Check50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt5dC.png)

Comment: I managed to recode it right.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/384b6a3e6ae91b9fcff2a52a436b7a22

Comment: You checked whether the median is the value. You want to check for `values[median] == value`, just like with the `else if` statement (and how you solved it)